# Serial Asynchrounous XmlHTTPRequest

Tags: javascript

Is this a better way to do a serial asyn call.

http://ajaxian.com/archives/serial-async-xhr

```
function run() { 
    request1(function () { 
        request2(function () { 
            request3(function () { 
                done(); 
            }); 
        }); 
    }); 
}
```

Will this cause a callback-hell problem?

Comment: No, callbacks are the way to go - but that code is hideous. I would write a wrapper for XHR considering how similar every function looks.

Comment: @Snuffleupagus: Can you show me an example for the same...

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* bulletproof and just to give you an example.

```
function ajax(url, callback) { 
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    req.open("GET", url, true); 
    req.onreadystatechange = function () { 
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) { 
            if(callback)
            {
                callback(this.responseText);
            }
        } 
    }; 
    req.send(); 
}
```

as a wrapper, so you end up doing something like

```
function loadIndex()
{
    ajax('/', function(data){
        alert(data);
        loadIndexAgain();
    });
}

function loadIndexAgain()
{
    ajax('/', function(data){
        alert('more stuff happened');
    });
}

loadIndex();
```

and your statements will be chained.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emosaurusrex/qQh5S/1/).